# Django: model maxlength and form maxlength

Tags: django, forms, model

I need to somehow hook the Model's max_length constraints into a Form object.

Say I define a Model with a field: `name = models.CharField(max_length=30)`
Now I define a Form object with the same field: `name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)`

Question is, is there someway to synchronize the two? If I define a Model first, could I define the `max_length` of the Form class based on what I did with the Model class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a ModelForm makes sense if you have a form related directly to a model.

Another way to pick up the max_length attribute from a model is to use the `_meta` attribute of the model like so:

```
>>> SomeModel._meta.get_field('some_field').max_length
64
>>>
```

so:

```
from models import *

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    some_field = forms.CharField(label='Some Field', 
            max_length=SomeModel._meta.get_field('some_field').max_length)
```

[**`CharField docs`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#charfield)

Answer (score 1):

Use ModelForms:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform
This way the forms inherit directly from the models and you do not have to repeat yourself.