# manual input field - value and maxlength

Tags: python, django, input, django-forms

To get some more control over my input fields, I try to "copy" the function that generates input fields in the template

I use a ModelForm and I want to change

```
...
{{ form.name }}
...
```

into something like

```
...
<input id="{{ form.name.auto_id }}" type="text" name="{{ form.name.name }}" maxlength="{{ form.name.**get_max_length** }}" value="{{ form.name.**get_value_or_initial_value** }}"/>
...
```

Most of that works already, except *maxlength* and *value*.

**maxlength**
I read

- [How can I programmatically obtain the max_length of a Django model field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829216/how-can-i-programmatically-obtain-the-max-length-of-a-django-model-field)
- [Django: model maxlength and form maxlength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922132/django-model-maxlength-and-form-maxlength)

but I still don't get it right...

**value**
The answer to this question ([How can you manually render a form field with its initial value set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929903/how-can-you-manually-render-a-form-field-with-its-initial-value-set)) points to a ticket which is fixed already. Still `name.value` would print "None" if there is no value present. Am I meant to catch `value="None"` manually or is there a better solution meanwhile?

*[edit]*
value seems to work like that

```
{{ form.name.value|default_if_none:"" }}
```

(from [Display value of a django form field in a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236691/display-value-of-a-django-form-field-in-a-template))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the max_length attribute from the widget. For the initial value, you only need to access the value attribute, there is already an initial or submitted value. All initial values passed to form class are held in form.initial, but you probably don't need to check these values:.

```
<input id="{{ form.name.auto_id }}" type="text" name="{{ form.name.name }}" maxlength="{{ form.name.field.widget.attrs.max_length }}" value="{% if form.name.value %}{{ form.name.value }}{% endif %}"/>
```

Comment: thanks! `value` seems to work (I also found a shortcut - see the edit in my question), however, I cannot get `max_length` to work like this. did you try it out?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the field attribute, it is fixed now. BoundField has no direct access to the widget.